# reinstall removed core packages

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management

I have accidentally deleted some Linux Mint Cinnamon default packages. (I have run `remove evolution-*' to remove Evolution related packages, but it includes some core packages).

So now I don't have packages like `nemo`, `cinnamon-settings` and so on.

What can I do to reinstall them? Without installing a fresh copy and loosing all personal data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
```

and you should see all the packages that were removed.  You should be able to re-install them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking and actually you can re-install evolution and use some data recovery tools.

You might want to take a look at : `sleuthkit`, `foremost` and [Data-Recovery on Linux and ext3](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/data-recovery-linux-and-ext3).

Comment: If I run `apt-get install evolution-*`, it would install all removed packages, but it will do it for unnecessary packages too, which I have not installed them before. (neither comes by default nor installed manually )